# Ruby on Rails - Action Mailer 400 Bad request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, bad-request

I'm having the following error when I try send a form with Ruby on Rails 4.1 and Action Mailer:

```
Started POST "/contact_sponsors" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-17 16:22:35 -0300
Processing by ContactSponsorsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "contact_sponsor"=>{"company_name"=>"godocu@mailinator.com", "company_cnpj"=>"dahok@mailinator.com", "company_cep"=>"watyhib@mailinator.com", "company_address"=>"dofimocah@mailinator.com", "company_number"=>"duki@mailinator.com", "company_existence"=>"mamopiwir@mailinator.net", "company_sponsor_type"=>"", "responsible_name"=>"qomukuf@mailinator.com", "responsible_email"=>"ryhohiqe@mailinator.net", "additional_infos"=>"Eum sit nesciunt occaecat facere delectus vel aut sint animi pariatur Ut ipsum officia ratione est enim est"}}
  HomeConfig Load (4.1ms)  SELECT  `home_configs`.* FROM `home_configs`   ORDER BY `home_configs`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 400 Bad Request in 16ms (Views: 0.8ms | ActiveRecord: 4.8ms)
```

Anyone can help me? I've tried to sort this out in many ways but to no avail. Here is my Controller, Mailer and Model:

```
class ContactSponsorsController < InheritedResources::Base
  def create
    @contact_sponsor = ContactSponsor.new
    if @contact_sponsor.save
      ContactSponsorMailer.delay_for(10.seconds, retry: true).create(@contact_sponsor)
      render nothing: true, status: 200
    else
      render nothing: true, status: 400
    end
  end
end

class ContactSponsorMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "Facens Lince <no-reply@facens.br>"

  def create(contact_sponsor)
    @contact_sponsor = contact_sponsor
    mail(to: "felipe.marcon@atua.ag", subject: "Contato Através do Site")
  end
end

class ContactSponsor < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :company_cnpj, :company_address, :company_number, :company_size, :company_existence, :company_sponsor_type, :responsible_name, :responsible_email, presence: true
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: `@contact_sponsor.save` might be false ...then it's `status: 400`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler And why `@contact_sponsor.save`? I'm trying find the problem, but still now I didn't found nothing. The code is pretty the same of other action mailer that I already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, in the `ContactSponsor` you have `validate` those data which must be present but you have not passed any data that means empty that's why

> Completed 400 Bad Request

and for this, you need to create a private method for [**`strong parameters`**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) look at that below

```
class ContactSponsorsController < InheritedResources::Base
    def create
        @contact_sponsor = ContactSponsor.new(contact_sponsor_params)
        if @contact_sponsor.save
            ContactSponsorMailer.delay_for(10.seconds, retry: true).create(@contact_sponsor)
            render nothing: true, status: 200
        else
            render nothing: true, status: 400
        end
    end

    private

    def contact_sponsor_params
        params.require(:contact_sponsor).permit(:company_cnpj, :company_address, :company_number, :company_size, :company_existence, :company_sponsor_type, :responsible_name, :responsible_email)
    end
end
```

I think it will work.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Initially the values of the options in select were blank as well. @Rohan made me realize that. Thanks both of you.

Answer (score 0):

`@contact_sponsor.save` returned `false` therefore it returns 400.
Check the errors you had with `@contact_sponsor.errors.full_messages` when it returns false, or use `save!` to raise an exception (discouraged, use it only for debugging) and see what went wrong.

Comment: If I use `save!` that says that field are blank, even if they are filled. If I take the validations of my model, then everything functional. What can it be?

Answer (score 0):

As per the logs shown and code snippet shared, it seems like the attribute "company_sponsor_type" seems to be blank string and in the model you have the written the presence true of the same attribute and thus it is getting rolled back.

So either remove the validation or send some value in the company_sponsor_type key.

Comment: If I remove the validations of my model, then everything functional. If I use save! in controller that says that field are blank, even if they are filled. What can it be?

Comment: As per the logs it shows that the value in params for a particular field is blank..please check if all the fields marked as validated have values . If anyone of the fields is blank then it will rollback...Please share the updated logs as well!!